# Data not being saved on user_save

Tags: 7, entities, database

I having a problem saving user data to the database. Everything is being saved apart from 'street_address', 'town_city', 'region' 'postal_code' and 'country'.

full module_create_user:

```
function openid_connect_create_user($sub, $userinfo, $client_name) {

  $address = $userinfo['address'];
  $decodeAddress = json_decode($address);

  $firstName = $userinfo['given_name'];
  $lastName = $userinfo['family_name'];


  $streetAddress2 = $decodeAddress->{"street_address"};
  $townCity2 = $decodeAddress->{"locality"};
  $region2 = $decodeAddress->{"region"};
  $postalCode2 = $decodeAddress->{"postal_code"};
  $country2 = $decodeAddress->{"country"};

  $streetAddress = (string)$streetAddress2;
  $townCity = (string)$townCity2;
  $region = (string)$region2;
  $postalCode = (string)$postalCode2;
  $country = (string)$country2;

  $edit = array(
    'name' => $firstName.$lastName.$sub, //works
    'pass' => user_password(), //works
    'mail' => $userinfo['email'], //works
    'init' => $userinfo['email'], //works
    'family_name' => $userinfo['family_name'], //works
    'given_name' => $userinfo['given_name'], //works
    'nickname' => $userinfo['nickname'], //works
    'gender' => $userinfo['gender'], //works
    'birthdate' => $userinfo['birthdate'], //works
    'phone_number' => $userinfo['phone_number'], //works
    'street_address' => $streetAddress, //doesn't work
    'town_city' => $townCity, //doesn't work
    'region' => $region, //doesn't work
    'postal_code' => $postalCode, //doesn't work
    'country' => $country, //doesn't work
    'status' => 1, //works
    'openid_connect_client' => $client_name, //works
    'openid_connect_sub' => $sub, //works
  );

  return user_save(NULL, $edit);
}
```

different $edit i've tried:

```
$edit = array(
    'name' => $firstName.$lastName.$sub, //works
    'pass' => user_password(), //works
    'mail' => $userinfo['email'], //works
    'init' => $userinfo['email'], //works
    'family_name' => $userinfo['family_name'], //works
    'given_name' => $userinfo['given_name'], //works
    'nickname' => $userinfo['nickname'], //works
    'gender' => $userinfo['gender'], //works
    'birthdate' => $userinfo['birthdate'], //works
    'phone_number' => $userinfo['phone_number'], //works
    'field_street_address_pixelpin' => $streetAddress, //doesn't work
    'field_town_city_pixelpin' => $townCity, //doesn't work
    'field_region_pixelpin' => $region, //doesn't work
    'field_postal_code_pixelpin' => $postalCode, //doesn't work
    'field_country_pixelpin' => $country, //doesn't work
    'status' => 1, //works
    'openid_connect_client' => $client_name, //works
    'openid_connect_sub' => $sub, //works
  );
```

examples of the fields which are being programmability created:

Family name (works):

```
if (!field_info_field('field_family_name_pixelpin')) {
    $field = array(
        'field_name' => 'field_family_name_pixelpin', 
        'type' => 'text', 
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    $instance = array(
        'field_name' => 'field_family_name_pixelpin', 
        'entity_type' => 'user', 
        'label' => 'Family Name', 
        'bundle' => 'user', 
        // If you don't set the "required" property then the field wont be required by default.
        'required' => FALSE,
        'settings' => array(
           // Here you inform either or not you want this field showing up on the registration form.
            'user_register_form' => 1,
        ),
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
        ),
        'display' => array(
          'default' => array('label' => 'above'),
      ),
    );
    field_create_instance($instance);
  }
```

postal code (doesn't work):

```
if(!field_info_field('field_postal_code_pixelpin')) {
    $field = array(
        'field_name' => 'field_postal_code_pixelpin', 
        'type' => 'text', 
    );
    field_create_field($field);
    $instance = array(
        'field_name' => 'field_postal_code_pixelpin', 
        'entity_type' => 'user', 
        'label' => 'Postal Code', 
        'bundle' => 'user', 
        // If you don't set the "required" property then the field wont be required by default.
        'required' => FALSE,
        'settings' => array(
           // Here you inform either or not you want this field showing up on the registration form.
            'user_register_form' => 1,
        ),
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
        ),
        'display' => array(
          'default' => array('label' => 'above'),
      ),
    );
    field_create_instance($instance);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for custom user fields, `user_save` requires the field values to be provided as an array. An example would be the following:

```
 $edit['field_yourfield'] = array(
   LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
     0 => array('value' => $yourValue),
   ),
 );
```

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: It works, well done.